# ссылка в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

у меня есть несколько рубрик web и mobail под эти категории сделаны разные шаблоны и в одной из рубрик мне надо что б по открытию поста открывалась не страница статьи на переходила по внешней ссылке которую укажут через админку

есть вот такой код но он не работает может кто то может подсказать какую то идею

```
 <div class="content_portfolio">

        <?php query_posts('category__in=58&showposts=100'); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


            <div class="link_portfolio snip1543">

                <!--виводим миниатюру-->

                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(array()); ?>" alt="image">
                <figcaption>

                    <!--заголовок поста-->

                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

                    <!--краткое описание поста-->

                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                </figcaption>

                <!--вывод ссылки на пост-->

                <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get( 'link-site' );?>"></a>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> надо что б по открытию поста открывалась не страница статьи на
>   переходила по внешней ссылке которую укажут через админку

Использовать [произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) или https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/

> query_posts

А по это читай [Почему не следует использовать query_posts() в WordPress](https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/)